# sba dep suitesparse

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone who had tried rosmake sba?
It gives the error below:

Failed to find rosdep suitesparse for package sba on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12237/sba-dep-suitesparse/) by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems repository link is not working, try to download suitsparse from its website and then install it retry rosmake after installing suitsparse.

---

Originally posted by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) with karma: 224 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1